# Can I delete .dylibs in usr/lib after uninstalling Homebrew?

Tags: osx-lion, troubleshooting, homebrew

I am in the process of uninstalling Homebrew from my Mac Lion 10.7.5.

I see that there are 181 .dylibs in the Macintosh HD/usr/lib folder that has the same "date created" when I installed Homebrew.

But there are 303 .dylibs with the same "last modified" date.

Can I just delete these files inside this folder (usr/lib)? Is it safe to do so? Are they all from Homebrew? I have already deleted everything in usr/local/ except for a folder from clamXav.

Thanks.

Edit 1: Just realised that these files I was talking about are "Alias". Does this mean I can delete?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where do the aliases point? Click on one and hit Cmd-i, and it will tell you. Check a few of them. Do they all point to somewhere in /usr/local?

Comment: @echristopherson, They point to the same folder as the alias themselves: usr/lib. A few that has a bigger size (118bytes) points to: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the aliases point to system locations (e.g. /usr/lib and /System/...), I would leave them there. If they pointed to /usr/local they would most probably be part of Homebrew, but even then I'd be afraid to delete them -- Homebrew doesn't install much of anything outside of that hierarchy (it might be true that it *never* does).

Perhaps they have the same date as the date when you installed Homebrew because you first installed Xcode that same day in order to use Homebrew. Or, if you already had Xcode, it or OS X might have been updated that day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just did a clean install of mac lion and I was hoping to maintain a good condition of the system files etc. I hope you're right and it's just Xcode files.